# Monero - Checkpoint Validation Failed

Tags: monerod, blockchain, miners

Could you help me with this error? I do not know what I'm doing wrong. I started to mine a fork of monero from block genesis, but I did the error that is seen in the image and I do not know where to investigate that error.
[image]

Comment: im actually looking on how to disable the checkpoints having a ton of trouble please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If you want to have a mainnet custom chain, remove the checkpoints in checkpoints.cpp (and disable that define)." -moneromooo, IRC, 2017-Oct

Comment: I have to deal with a fork that made changes so it wants to have at least one checkpoint. I can't make any RPC call before hand. Do you know how to generate the first checkpoint for my custom chain? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/14027/how-to-generate-a-checkpoint-for-checkpoint-cpp