# How to generate a checkpoint for checkpoint.cpp?

Tags: monero-forks, genesisblock

I'd like to know how checkpoints for the monero network are formed and hardcoded in the checkpoint.cpp. Especially when having a fresh fork with the first genesis block having to be made. How to effectively generate the very first checkpoint?

From the Monero source code:

```
    ADD_CHECKPOINT2(1,     "771fbcd656ec1464d3a02ead5e18644030007a0fc664c0a964d30922821a8148", "0x2");
    ADD_CHECKPOINT2(10,    "c0e3b387e47042f72d8ccdca88071ff96bff1ac7cde09ae113dbb7ad3fe92381", "0x2a974");
    ADD_CHECKPOINT2(100,   "ac3e11ca545e57c49fca2b4e8c48c03c23be047c43e471e1394528b1f9f80b2d", "0x35d14b");
    ADD_CHECKPOINT2(1000,  "5acfc45acffd2b2e7345caf42fa02308c5793f15ec33946e969e829f40b03876", "0x36a0373");
    ADD_CHECKPOINT2(10000, "c758b7c81f928be3295d45e230646de8b852ec96a821eac3fea4daf3fcac0ca2", "0x60a91390");
```

What are those values? Height, block hash, checksum? How are those created specifically?

Additionally, it would be useful to know what effect the `PER_BLOCK_CHECKPOINT` flag has on checkpoints in general.

### Update

I figured out the checkpoint consists out of "height", "transaction id" and "cumulative difficulty" and can be received from the daemon via RPC call:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_block_header_by_height","params":{"height":2851000}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

But, how can I send this RPC call when the daemon wouldn't pass the first block being validated?

### Update 2

When the database is finally created, the daemon will retrieve the "block hash" of the first block via:

```
mdb_block_info* bi = (mdb_block_info*)result.mv_data;
crypto::hash ret = bi->bi_hash;
```

The daemon will print an `EXPECTED HASH` and a `GIVEN HASH`, neither of those work in the `checkpoints.cpp`, I guess because this is the hash of the transaction ID?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is fairly not a default Monero fork I have to deal with, but I want to give some information about these checkpoints so other people don't have to suffer that much. I finally figured it out by logging what needed to be logged.

Before @jtgrassie could explain it, I already noticed the Genesis TX does not work as checkpoint hash. But, when the database is finally created, the daemon will retrieve the "block hash" of the first block via:

```
mdb_block_info* bi = (mdb_block_info*)result.mv_data;
crypto::hash ret = bi->bi_hash;
```

The daemon will print such `GIVEN HASH` within its error. Since the operation requires the database which is not in place on the genesis tx generation itself, I have to recompile twice. Once I have the error message, I can input the `GIVEN HASH` into my `checkpoints.cpp`.

But it didn't work and this through me off-guard for hours. Apparently, the previously wrong hash was written to the database and all I had to do is reset the database, now it would pass the checkpoint validation.

Answer (score 2):

> How to effectively generate the very first checkpoint?

Mine a block and use it's block hash, height and difficulty.

> What are those values? Height, block hash, checksum? How are those created specifically?

They are height, block hash and difficulty ([src](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/00fd416a99686f0956361d1cd0337fe56e58d4a7/src/checkpoints/checkpoints.h#L39)).

> Additionally, it would be useful to know what effect the PER_BLOCK_CHECKPOINT flag has on checkpoints in general.

Whether or not to use the compiled-in checkpoints.

> But, how can I send this RPC call when the daemon wouldn't pass the first block being validated?

The parameter height. Height 0 is the genesis block, height 1 is the first block being "validated".

> I guess because this is the hash of the transaction ID?

No, it's the block hash.

Comment: Thanks for explaining a bit about this, especially that it's the block hash and not txid. How would I mine the first block when the daemon won't start? Also`PER_BLOCK_CHECKPOINT` seems to not disable checkpoints entirely, at least for my fork. Please check my answer to see why I struggled so much and how I could fix it eventually.

Comment: I never said PER_BLOCK_CHECKPOINT would disable/enable checkpoints, I said "Whether or not to use the *compiled-in* checkpoints."

Comment: Sorry, but I was talking about these, because I couldn't bypass the issue by disabling `PER_BLOCK_CHECKPOINT`. I would still try to validate my hardcoded checkpoint which I assume is the compiled-in checkpoint.

Comment: You asked *"what effect the PER_BLOCK_CHECKPOINT flag has on checkpoints in general"*, not how to disable/bypass.